# Having a child modify its parent

Tags: rust

I want to have a child struct modify its parent struct.
Example:

```
// Problem: Having a struct's field modify the struct in which the field is.

// MUST NOT be copyable nor clonable
struct Updatee {
    value: u64,
    updater: Updater
}

impl Updatee {
    fn update(&mut self) {
        // ERROR: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
        self.updater.update(self);
    }
}

// MUST NOT be copyable nor clonable
struct Updater {
    value: u64
}

impl Updater {
    fn update(&mut self, updatee: &mut Updatee) {
        self.value = self.value + 1;
        updatee.value = self.value;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let updater = Updater { value: 0 };
    let updatee = Updatee { value: 0, updater: updater };

    updatee.update();
    updatee.update();

    assert_eq!(2, updatee.value);
}
```

I'm sure it can be done with unsafe blocks, but is there an alternative?
Perhaps my code is not idiomatic?

Comment: `self.updater.update(self);` You should not even need to do this. Rust take a lot of inspiration from functional programming, I don't think you would like to have this design even in OO-heavy langauge like Java.

Comment: Why do you need updater to be inside updatee.

Comment: Also... you need to use explicit lifetimes... for such setup.

Comment: 1) I need the updater to be inside the updatee because I iterator over them and call the `Updatee.update()` method. They update "themselves", but I need the update mechanism (the updater) to be swappable i.e. some updatee have different update strategy.  
  
2) I don't think you'd need lifetimes for this, since updatee own the updater.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you are getting the "already borrowed" error is because you are trying to pass the `Updater` to its `update` method twice, once as `self`, and once embedded inside of `updatee`. For memory safety reasons, Rust doesn't allow that.

The simplest solution would be to pass to `update` a reference to the field in `Updatee` that needs to be updated rather than the entire `Updatee`:

```
impl Updater {
    fn update(&mut self, updatee_value: &mut u64) {
        self.value = self.value + 1;
        *updatee_value = self.value;
    }
}
```

If multiple fields need to be updated, `Updatee` could be transformed into a wrapper around the `Updater` and another struct that holds the fields with the actual data, which could be safely passed to `update`.

Comment: Didn't think of using a wrapper, sure it's better than unsafe, but it still is ugly. It means I need a "public" `Updatee` and a "private" `_Updatee`. However if I want to allow external implementation of custom updaters, I would have to make both public... It's a good idea but it's a bummer that I have to go to this length to implement such a simple thing. Thanks!